# In d3 sequential.interpolator, is it possible to only use a portion of the spectrum?

Tags: d3.js, colors

In d3 sequential.interpolator, is it possible to only use only a segment of the spectrum instead of the full range? It seems such palette only requires an input of domain and not range, wonder if it's possible to specify something only to take the middle or lower portion of the color spectrum. Thanks.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I don't think so. You can always use [d3-interplolate](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate#interpolateRgb) to create a custom colour interpolation between the colours you actually want though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to create a custom interpolator, you could achieve the effect you are looking for two ways:

- modifying the domain,
- changing how t is calculated for the interpolator.

If you assign a domain to the scale that has twice the extent of the actual domain of your data, then you will use only half the range of colors.

But, I'll expand on the second one here, as it allows you to modify the type of scale easily too. The `t` parameter for the interpolator is a value from 0 to 1:

> Given a number t in the range [0,1], returns the corresponding color
>   from the ... scheme represented as an RGB string. ([from the API docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic)).

We can manipulate `t` in a few ways so that we only use a portion of the color ramp. For example, to show only colors from the first half of the ramp we can ensure that `t` never exceeds 0.5:

```
var truncated = d3.scaleSequential(function(t) {    
     return d3.interpolateViridis((t/2)) })
  .domain([1,10]);
```

Or to get the middle:

```
var middle = d3.scaleSequential(function(t) {
    return d3.interpolateViridis(t/2+0.25) })
  .domain([1,10]);
```

*If using something like `t*2`, values that exceed 1 or are below 0 will be shown as either extreme.*

You can also do things like skew the colors by using the square root or some other power of t, which may be useful when dealing with non-linear data.

```js
var scale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis)
   .domain([1,10]); 

var truncated = d3.scaleSequential(function(t) {    
     return d3.interpolateViridis((t/2)) })
  .domain([1,10]);
  
var middle = d3.scaleSequential(function(t) {
    return d3.interpolateViridis(t/2+0.25)
})
  .domain([1,10]);

var data = d3.range(10);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg");
  
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d * 12 + 12; })
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return scale(d); })
  
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d * 12 + 12; })
  .attr("y", 32)
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return truncated(d); })
  
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d * 12 + 12; })
  .attr("y", 44)
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return middle(d); })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
```